# CentOS Yum Not Finding Packages

Tags: centos, exfat

Just installed CentOS and am trying to install exfat-utils and fuse-exfat but yum says "No package .. Available" for both when I try "sudo yum install exfat-utils." Maybe I am missing some repositories or something?

Answer (score 4):

On CentOS, install those with the command:

`sudo yum install exfat-utils fuse-exfat`

You can see that those packages are hosted on **nux-dextop repo**:

```
`exfat-utils-1.0.1-1.el7.nux.x86_64 : Utilities for exFAT file system
Repo        : nux-dextop
fuse-exfat-1.0.1-1.el7.nux.x86_64 : Free exFAT file system implementation
Repo        : nux-dextop`
```

If you don't have this repo yet, just add it first. Look in http://li.nux.ro/repos.html for the current version. And note that it also depends on [epel-release](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

```
yum -y install epel-release http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-5.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: If you get an error while trying to install the repo saying "... does not update installed package. Nothing to do", it may because you already have it but it is "disabled". Check with `yum repolist all` and if needed, enable it with `yum --enablerepo=nux-dextop`.

Answer (score 0):

Install packages using

```
sudo yum install -y exfatprogs
```

Then you can make the partition with `exfat` file system

```
sudo mkfs.exfat /dev/sdb1
```